# How to compare an integer and a string in C#?

Tags: c#, loops, sum

So, I need the app to stop doing something if the input is "X". Problem is, the previous input is integer, x is seen as a string, how do I compare the two? 
This is my bit of code

```
int sum = 0;
while (true)
{
    string inputData = Console.ReadLine();
    int input = Convert.ToInt32(inputData);
    sum += input;

    if (input.Equals("x", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        break;
    }                              
}
```

Please and thank you.

Comment: How do you imagine the character `x` would ever be equal to a number?

Comment: How can an integer be `"x"`? Do you mean the ASCII value of `'x'`? Please clarify your question

Comment: Simply move the `if` checking for the `"x"` right after getting input and before the conversion to int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you wanted to do sum the next number until user press 'x' character.

```
int sum = 0;
while (true)
{
    string inputData = Console.ReadLine();

    if (inputData.Equals("x", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
     {
         break;
     }

     int input = Convert.ToInt32(inputData);
      sum += input;
 }


 Console.WriteLine("Total sum is : " + sum);
 Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: I would add something about `FormatException` and `Convert.ToInt32` or the use of `int.TryParse`

Comment: @Igor agreed. Looks like he is just learning C# so I didn't added extra.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the character X to be entered on the input to stop the app from processing then you need to check if the string is the value X **before** converting the input to an integer. You are then comparing 2 strings and not a string and an integer.

Then when you know you do not have an X - you can continue to try to convert your input to an integer for use in the app. You should probably be using a int.TryParse method. See docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-number

```
int sum = 0;
while (true)
{
   string inputData = Console.ReadLine();

   if (inputData.Equals("x", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
   {
       break;
   }

   int input = 0;
   if (Int32.TryParse(inputData, out input))
   {
     sum += input;
   }
}


Console.WriteLine("Total sum is : " + sum);
Console.ReadLine();
```